# Difficult to replicate objects (Customers) on the list?

Tags: c#, file, data-access-layer

I wrote a program that does work with files like delete and update, store, and search
And all customers
But I have a problem with the method is LoadAll
Once the data are read from the file and then Deserialize the object becomes
But when I want to save the list of objects in the list are repeated.
How can I prevent the duplication in this code?

```
var customerStr = File.ReadAllLines (address);
```

The code is written in CustomerDataAccess class DataAccess Layer.

**[Project File](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xy6rp1rghyqjrs8/CoustomersApp.rar)**

The main problem with the method LoadAll Code:

```
      public ICollection<Customer> LoadAll()
    {
        var alldata = File.ReadAllLines(address);

        List<Customer> lst = new List<Customer>();

        foreach (var s in alldata)
        {
            var objCustomer = customerSerializer.Deserialize(s);
            lst.Add(objCustomer);
        }

        return lst;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CustomerSerialize class defined in a Field you simply use the Deserialize method you! Each series is a series Deserialize the value added items previously got into the game! (Because there is reference Type).

If you change your code to:

```
     public Customer Deserialize(string str)
    {
        **Customer customer = new Customer();**
        var strCustomer = str.Split(',');

        customer.Id = int.Parse(strCustomer[0]);
        customer.FirstName = strCustomer[1];
        customer.LastName = strCustomer[2];
        customer.Age = int.Parse(strCustomer[3]);
        customer.Country = strCustomer[4];

        return customer;
    }
```